# Accessing private servers with one public IP

Tags: networking, cloud

I would love to have some views in the following use case of mine.

I have 'N' number of servers with private IP addresses running 'M' services on 'M' ports (same in all). Now I want all these services to be accessed using one public IP address.

I can use port forwarding but don't want to. For example:

PublicIP: 950    PriavteIP1:950

PublicIp:960     PrivateIP1:960

PublicIP:951     PrivateIP2:950

PublicIP:961     PrivateIP2:960

But don't want to do that.

Can anyone suggest me any method to achieve it?
For example: 
I have a public dns name example.com.

If there is query for xyz.example.com, it should be forward to one private server and if there is query for abc.example.com, it should be routed to second private server.

Thanks in Advance.

Ravi

Answer (score 0):

HTTP supports [Virtual Hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting), so you can achieve what you need installing a reverse proxy, but that's not true for all services/protocols.

If a a service/protocol doesn't support virtual hosting then port forwarding is your only choice.